# How to set a List<List<String>> in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following variable:

```
List<List<String>> selection = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Where after I do my adds to populate the `selections`

I want to modify one of the entries using the .set function like so:

```
selection.set(10, "modifiedentry");
```

But I am getting an error where I am provideing a String and not a List

How do I provide a List in my case?

Comment: If you need a singleton, fixed-length list, `List.of("modifiedentry")` should do the trick.

Comment: First, what list implementation do you want to provide? Second, if this is what you want to be doing, why bother with the list of lists structure?

Comment: `selection` is a list of lists, so you should add lists to it. In the 10th position, you are attempting to set a string, that's why you are getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set one value in every List you could do

```
selection.forEach(element -> element.set(10, "modifiedentry"));
```

To set the value of one element you could do something like

```
selection.get(0).set(10, "modifiedentry");
```

Answer (score 1):

In general when doing something like the following:

```
List<List<String>> selection = new ArrayList<>();
selection.set(10, "modifiedentry");
```

- You need to add a list and not a string to `selection`

```
selection.add(List.of("modifiedentry"));
```

If you want to make that added list mutable, pass it to an `ArrayList<>()` constructor before adding it.

```
selection.add(new ArrayList<>(List.of("modifiedentry")));
```

You can't `set` at a specific index unless that index already contains an element.

- So if selection is empty, you can't do

```
selection.set(10,List.of("modifiedentry"));
```

unless items 0 thru 10 exist. You will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

you list is of type- list of String. So to modify a value you have to enter the list of String in second parameter of the method set()

```
selection.set(10, Arrays.asList(new String [] {"modifiedentry"}));
```